# Spock No thread-bound request found

Tags: grails, spock

I have created a simple util class UtilService.groovy and when I tried to run write test case for it.
class UtilService {

```
static transactional = true

def messageSource


HttpServletRequest getCurrentRequest() {
    GrailsWebRequest webUtils = WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest()
    def request = webUtils.getCurrentRequest()
    return request
}

String getMessage(String code, Object[] args = null, String defaultMessage = null) {
    HttpServletRequest request = currentRequest
    Locale locale = request.locale
    if (defaultMessage) {
        return messageSource.getMessage(code, args, defaultMessage, locale)
    } else {
        return messageSource.getMessage(code, args, locale)
    }
}
```

Test case

```
@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
class UtilServiceSpec extends Specification {

    void "Test get message"() {
        setup:
            def utilService = new UtilService()

        when:
            String data = utilService.getMessage("payCode.label")

        then:
            data == "Pay Code"
    }
}
```

Error:

```
No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread?
```

I have searched and try some links from google but they did not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written Integration test for this requirement rather than Unit test and able to run my  test cases successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you are doing it outside of web request, WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest() will fail because there's no web request going on. If your service is called from a controller during tests it should work.

Instead of you service depending on WebRequest, why don't you pass the Locale as an argument to getMessage, controllers can call getMessage and pass the request Locale, or else the service will choose the default locale. Its generally not good idea to have services be aware of web apis (eg requests, response, session etc). And you will be able to test both service and controller.

Comment: I have tried to hard code the locale and but I was  getting exception for Locale.ENGLISH/Locale.US `org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'payCode.label' for locale 'en'.`

Comment: That mean you do not have messages.properties for that locale

Comment: I have all the message in default message.properties file. Could you tell me what Local should I have to pass in order to read message from default message.properties file